# Voiceover default focus behavior different in two ios version

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview, voiceover

Voiceover's default focus behaviour is different in different ios version.

I got an app open web without showing url bar.

I have two different iPhone version (12.1.3 , 12.3.1) With voiceover "ON".

In 12.1.3 , Enter a web page or reload ,voiceover will automatically focus on first element , (In the website is a button on top-left corner) .

But in 12.3.1 , voiceover's focus will find the closest element around last element which have focus.

For example , I press a button A to enter another page .

- 12.1.3 will automatically focus on top left corner button.
- 12.3.1 will find nearest focusable element around previous "button A focus area".

This is annoying. I have check two device, their voiceover setting seems to be the same.

And I try on safari. Both device will focus on url bar after enter new page.

I did have search iOS release note but not getting anything about this strange behaviour.

It is better to focus on first element for voiceover user.

Any help is appreciate, Thanks.

Comment: Hey! Did you find anything to solve this issue? Thanks